# Cómo calcular las horas restantes desde tiempo actual a una hora especifica del día siguiente en UNIX

Tags: php

Quiero obtener la cantidad de horas restantes desde el tiempo actual hasta una especifica del día siguiente con unix timestamp.

```
$now = time(); // Tiempo actual en unix

$horas_restantes = $hora_manana - $now; // Debería calcular el tiempo actual hasta la hora de mañana
```

Comment: Debe devolver el tiempo restante en unix también. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien con `strtotime` como muestras en tu código se obtiene la marca de tiempo en formato `UNIX` no lo considero el modo adecuado de calcular la diferencia con respecto a lo que tengas en la variable `now()` puesto que:

- Primero deberías obtener la diferencia de hrs. entre una fecha y otra y luego tranformar esa marca de tiempo ahora si a UNIX

Código

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");

$fecha1 = new DateTime();
$fecha1->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$fecha2 = new DateTime("2020-01-05 03:00:00");
$fecha2->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$fecha3 = $fecha1->diff($fecha2)->format("%H:%i:%s");

echo "Diferencia de horas: ".$fecha3.PHP_EOL;
$horas = strtotime($fecha3);
echo "Diferencia en UNIX: ".$horas;

echo PHP_EOL;
echo "De UNIX a formato: ".date("H:i:s", 1578124075);
```

Con una salida como esta:

```
Diferencia de horas: 01:47:49
Diferencia en UNIX: 1578124069
De UNIX a formato: 01:47:49
```

- Creamos 2 instancias de la clase `DateTime`, una para la fecha actual y otra para la fecha futura
- Ambas las formateamos para que tengan una salida de: `Y-m-d H:i:s`
- Calculamos la diferencia entre las 2 fechas con la función `diff`
- A la diferencia anterior le damos salida de `%H:%i:%s`
- La eventual salida que tengamos en *UNIX* la podemos transformar nuevamente a un formato legible con la función `date`

**Fuentes de consulta**

- [timezone PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)
- [strtotime PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php)
- [date en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Para que la fecha posterior es decir la del día de *mañana* que es contra la cual quieres obtener la diferencia de horas respecto de una fecha previa, hacemos uso de la función `modify()` para cambiar la marca de fecha.

Lograrías de cierto modo *darle dinamismo* para establecer la fecha del día siguiente sin tener que escribirla de forma netamente manual dentro de la instancia de la clase `DateTime()`

**EJEMPLO**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");

$fecha = new DateTime();
$fechaFinal = $fecha->modify("+1 day");

echo $fechaFinal->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

La fecha que obtendriamos originalmente sería:

> 2020-01-04 13:10:48

Pero con el uso de `modify` ahora veremos

> 2020-01-05 13:10:48

**Referencia**

- [Función modify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.modify.php)

Comment: Todo bien, pero donde pones $fecha2 = new DateTime("2020-01-05 03:00:00"); quería saber como sacarlo automático a esa hora especifica de mañana, por ejemplo del tiempo actual: 2020-01-04 12:00:00 cuanto falta para 2020-01-05 03:00:00 pero necesito que sea automático a una hora que yo especifique, no se si me entienda. Gracias.

Comment: cosa que yo pueda cambiar la hora pero la fecha sea automática del día de mañana, no me sirve calculando de 2020-01-04 00:00:00 a 2020-01-05 00:00:00, lo que busco es asignar la hora no la fecha.

Comment: checa si lo que actualizaré te ayuda @LuisSandrea, ia idea es poner la fecha completa para calcular la diferencia de horas entre una marca de tiempo completo y otra, por que ¿qué pasa si no es un día de diferencia si no 4, cómo sabría tu código que las horas a contar de 10 am y 22 am son de 4 días diferentes y no de 2?

Comment: Mi programa funciona así: En un enlace limito los clics diarios a 3 (solo 3 veces se puede hacer clic en el link en 1 día) pero me falta guardar en la base de datos el tiempo exacto cuando se hizo el último clic y este para poder diferenciarlo con la fecha del día siguiente y saber si los clics están habilitados o aún no ha llegado al día siguiente.

Answer (score 0):

Perdón, acabo de darme cuenta de que pides la diferencia de tiempo en formato UNIX, entonces quédate únicamente con los segundos, porque el formato UNIX es el número de segundos transcurridos desde 1970, entiendo que para usar la función `date()`:

```
<?php
$gmt=date('O')/100; //Diferencia de la hora de Greenwich (GMT) en horas
$manana = '2020-01-05 18:00';
$s = strtotime($manana)-time();
echo date('d H:i:s',$s-(24+$gmt)*60*60);
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta que, al calcular la diferencia, el instante de referencia de 1970, se pierde. Así que esos segundos de diferencia serán de 1970, no de hoy. Es decir, no calcules fechas con ese dato.

Esto sería una cuenta atrás en horas con sus minutos y segundos, sin complicarse con formatos UNIX ni GMT:

```
<?php
$manana = '2020-01-05 18:00';
$s = strtotime($manana)-time();
$h = floor($s/(60*60));
$m = floor($s/60)-$h*60;
$s = $s-$h*60*60-$m*60;
$h = sprintf('%02d',$h);
$m = sprintf('%02d',$m);
$s = sprintf('%02d',$s);
echo "$h:$m:$s hasta mañana";
```

Seguro que habrá funciones más sofisticadas, pero nada como lo que se aprende de niño de multiplicar y dividir por 60.

La verdad es que aquí hay poco que explicar:

- `time()` devuelve segundos
- `strtotime()` también devuelve segundos, aunque ojo al formato de la fecha que no los acepta todos
- `floor()` redondea hacia abajo
- `sprintf()` es para que muestre dos dígitos
- y el resto es lo que harías con lápiz y papel